# How can I do a on_conflict_replace work in Django batch_create operation?

Tags: python, django

The field `account` and `month` are unique togather. And I'm tring to `batch_insert` db data by `bulk_create` with `Django` to speed up my db operation.

My db backend is `mysql` with `innodb`

below is my base table

```
# my db table 

class MSpendForMonth(models.Model):
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    system_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2)
    checked_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(MAccount,
                                models.DO_NOTHING,
                                related_query_name="account_month",
                                related_name="account_month"
                                )
   
    month = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'spend_for_month'
        unique_together = (('account', 'month'),)


# db operation

bulk_data = []
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        for spend_data in spend_month_date_sum_queryset:
            bulk_data.append(
                MSpendForMonth(
                    account_id=spend_data["account_id"],
                    month=month,
                    system_value=spend_data["sum_value"],
                )
            )
        MSpendForMonth.objects.bulk_create(bulk_data, ignore_conflicts=True )
        # MSpendForMonth.objects.bulk_update(bulk_data, fields="system_value")
except:
    import traceback as tb
    tb.print_exc()
```

And I want to replace `system_value` with a new value as it sometimes changed.

My question is how can I `bulk_create` data and replace with new value of `system_value` if there is a conflict on unique key `account-month`.

It should be something like [insert_many().on_conflict_replace() -- peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html)

Great thanks.

Comment: No such functionality exists in core Django, you either have to run some raw SQL or find a package. Which database are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks for reply, my db backend is `mysql`

Comment: There is this package https://pypi.org/project/django-bulk-update-or-create/ although I’m not sure it actually does an upset. Raw SQL is probably your only option right now